# How to get .val() value of texbox created by ajax

Tags: jquery

I have html textbox

```
 <input type="text" id="inputfilter" style="width: 230px;" />
```

I'm creating this input dynamically via AJAX .

How can I retrieve a value of this checkbox? I tried

```
$("#inputfilter").val()
```

But didn't work because textbox was not created on page initialization but later via AJAX .
I tried things like this

```
$("#inputfilter").live('val', function(e) {})
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: is there a form parent to that input?

Comment: What are you using the value for?  You could edit your ajax request to update whatever you're using it for

Comment: Assuming `$(#inputfilter).val() ` was a typo for `$("#inputfilter").val() `. Did you add the text box to the dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#inputfilter").val()
```

should work. The only reason I can think of it's not working is that you tried to retrieve the value before you created the element (and I assume here that you managed to create the element, with the correct `id`.. but hell, you never know).

Note: `.live` is for event handling like clicks, so it's not relevant here (but yes, with events that's one way to go).

Comment: yes, you are right it works, I got it.. I made stupid mistake so it didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `append()` to create the control dynamically, then your approach should be fine. Try my test code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K9fPF/).

My test code simulates the ajax call and then set and retrieve the value, it works.

```
<div id="parentId"></div>

setTimeout(function () {
    $('#parentId').append('<input type="text" id="inputfilter" style="width: 230px;" />')
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
    $('#inputfilter').val('test');
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log($('#inputfilter').val());
}, 4000);
```